# Hard word wrap after preprocessing in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, erb

I'm writing the text version of a Rails mailer email (an example.text.erb file) and I'd like it to display for the recipient with clean breaks after an arbitrary number of characters, say 70.  Sublime lets you select a number of paragraphs and break them at the ruler or a fixed char point using Edit >> Wrap >> "Wrap Paragraph at Ruler" but this also includes all the erb code that I've put in (so it's counting the <%= link_to example... %> and not the actual link text output).

This makes the resulting text email that gets sent to the recipient uneven and disjointed because the erb code takes up a number of characters unrelated to the length of its text output.

What's the best way to wrap the text in a *.text.erb file with hard line breaks AFTER the erb has run?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it just evenly spaced out on your editor screen, or actually spaced out nicely once the ERB is evaluated and emailed off to the user? If that's the case, the only thing that comes to mind is gathering up your email in a string, then using Ruby to group that strings in to parts of equal length (say 70), then outputting each line for the email.

Comment: I'm looking to get it evenly spaced once the user receives it.  I was hoping there's some solution already available that I've overlooked instead of having to hack it together myself... I can't be the only person who's tried this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to process the text after it's run through ERB. My initial thought is you could 1) create a custom template handler or 2) hack something together to run a file through ERB and then work on the resulting text.

Also of note is the TextHelper#word wrap method which may be of help to you:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap